# Getting proxy settings from electron

Tags: proxy, electron

When i set proxy settings in the system my Electron application gets it automatically for common requests (axios package), but not for websockets (socket.io-client package). If i provide proxy settings manually then websockets starts to work too, but i want to try to avoid manual configuration, because it may be tricky to the real app's users. So i'm looking any way to get proxy settings from electron and transfer them to the websockets.

I have tried to use login event for my browserWindow in the both main and renderer process, but it doesn't trigger at all. Is there any way to get proxy settings that electron uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. It's possible to take proxy-settings inside the main process.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({})
const ses = mainWindow.webContents.session;
ses.resolveProxy('url_you_need_to_achieve', (proxy) => {
    // do whatever you want with proxy string, that contains proxy-setting
});
```