# Getting proxy bypass rules from electron

Tags: proxy, electron, system, amazon-ses, rules

I have an electron app which gets system proxy settings using the method available [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452645/getting-proxy-settings-from-electron/47476825#47476825)
I also need to get the 'Ignore Hosts' or proxyByPass system rules using [ses.resolveProxy()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md) (if possible). How can i achieve this?